# Oracle temporary table report creation

Tags: oracle

Temporary tables report creation

Users table

```
User id  User name 
1         user1
2         user2
3         user3
```

USER_IN_ROLES table

```
USRINR_USER_ID   USRINR_ROLES_ID

1                        103
3                        104
2                        105
1                        107
2                        108
1                        105
1                        108
```

roles rl

```
Roles ID                 Description
104                      User management
107                      Modify
103                      Debit
105                      General
108                      Audit
```

Relation User id between table 1 & 2 and roles id between 2 & 3

I would like a query that will give an op like this

```
UName   FirstEntitl     Second Entitl
user1    Team           Debit
user3   Security admin  User Management
user2   Read only user  General
user1   Team            Modify
user2   Read only user  Audit
user1   Team            General
user1   Team            Audit
```

So all users who have user management as role( no other roles) will be Security admin A users who have modify role will be team and if a user doesn't have modify and user management is a read only user. User 1 is TEAM so when he has another entitlement as General still column 2 should have him as team.   IF user has Modify then all the other rows for the user should have Team.  USer is a Reead only user as he doesnt have Modify anywhere. User 3 is little easy he is Sec Admin if he has User Management.

Comment: Gives me below error                                                                      ORA-00904: "COUNT_OF_ROLES"."USER_ID": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier" *Cause: *Action: Error at Line: 10 Column: 50

Comment: "Please write my query for me" does not make a good question on StackOverflow

Comment: `select usr.user_id, rl.role_code as firstentitl,
     Case
     When rl.role_code = 'UserManagement' then 'Sec Admin'
     When rl.role_code  = 'ManualModification' then 'BelgiumTax User'
     Else 'Read Only User'
     End as secondEntitileme
     from users usr, USER_IN_ROLES uir,  roles rl
     where usr.user_id=uir.usinr_user_id 
     and rl.role_id=uir.usinr_role_id;`
                                                                                                          I wrote this query but i get all read only user even for an user who is a team ,

Comment: I think i might need a temporary table created and then join it to my main query

Comment: `select usr.user_id, usr.user_login, rl.role_code as firstentitl,
 Case  When uir.usinr_user_id in (select usinr_user_id from user_in_roles where usinr_role_id in (
select role_id from roles where role_code = 'ManualModification')) then 'BelgiumTax User'  When uir.usinr_user_id in (select usinr_user_id from user_in_roles where usinr_role_id in (
select role_id from roles where role_code = 'UserManagement')) then 'Security Admin'  Else 'Read Only User'
   End as secondEntitileme
from users usr, USER_IN_ROLES uir,  roles rl
where usr.user_id=uir.usinr_user_id 
and rl.role_id=uir.usinr_role_id; `

Comment: Thats the answer i wrote it myself thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, I think this simple query would do it

```
SELECT  a.user_name as UName,
        decode(count_of_roles.nbRoles,
               1, decode(b.id,
                        107, 'Team', -- Display team as it is the only role
                        104, 'Security admin', -- Display Security admin as it is the only role
                        'Read only user'), -- If only one role was found, but neither team or admin we display Read only user 
               'Read only user') as "First Entitl", -- Display Read only user if more then one role was found
        c.description as "Second Entitl"
FROM users a
JOIN users_in_roles b on a.user_id = b.usrinr_user_id
JOIN roles_rl c on c.roles_id = b.usrinr_roles_id
JOIN (SELECT a.user_id, count(b.usrinr_roles_id) as nbRoles -- Join on a result set giving the nb of roles for the current user.
       FROM users a
       JOIN user_in_roles b ON a.user_id = b.usrinr_roles_id
       GROUP BY a.user_id) count_of_roles ON a.user_id = count_of_roles.user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks Jean i got the answer myself ... but really appreciate your help